# Opening a closed application from the dock after pressing X button in Kotlin Multiplatform

Tags: desktop, kotlin-multiplatform

Hi for some reason I can't find this answer anywhere.

I can't reopen my application when I close it using the application dock, I can only reopen using the tray to set isOpen back to true.

Code in question:

```
Tray(
    icon = TrayIcon,
    menu = {
        Item(
            "Exit",
            onClick = { exitApplication() }
        )
        Item(
            "Open",
            onClick = {isOpen.value = true}
        )
    }
)
if(isOpen.value) {
    Window(
        onCloseRequest = { isOpen.value = false },
        title = "Teamcity Desktop",
        state = rememberWindowState(width = 800.dp, height = 900.dp)
    ) {}
```

After pressing the X button on my application the window for it disappears (naturally). However the odd part is that I cannot find the way to make it reappear when you click the application icon in the application dock on mac os. The only way to make it reappear is to go to the tray and use the "Open" item. Does anyone know how I would listen for or use a application dock click to reopen the app?

Maybe I need to change my "onCloseRequest" strategy completely?